# Integrate Spring Boot with existing Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring Boot. I have gone through the documents and few tutorials. What I understood from them, Spring Boot makes development easy. Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade Spring based Applications that you can "just run".
Till tutorials it was fine.

But suppose you already have an application (SpringMVC+Hibernate+MySql) can I take advantage of Spring Boot in this application? To figure out answer I decided to integrate Spring Boot in one project. I downloaded a sample working code from http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial and tried to integrate Spring Boot. I am not able to get this working. I am getting below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:414)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:394)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:385)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:263)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at com.journaldev.spring.Application.main(Application.java:14)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
```

Now I am completely confused. I am getting impression that Spring Boot cannot be integrated above kind of application. You need to devlop application from scratch. Not sure whether I am correct or not. Please explain me how can I take advantages of Spring Boot in already developed Spring application?

Below is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.journaldev.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVCHibernate</artifactId>
<name>SpringMVCHibernate</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: I tried a lot to resolve the exception but not able to do so.

Comment: Which starter modules are you using to set up the Spring boot application?

Comment: Pls share your pom.xml

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from adding (or moving) Spring Boot to an existing application. However you might need to take some steps to make it work, one of them is to make sure you have a correct Spring version and judging from the exception you aren't using Spring 4.2 (which is needed for the most recent Spring Boot version).

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I was out of town. Added pom.xml in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener
```

From the above error, application is unable to find the class defined from the jar dependencies. `GenericApplicationListener` is added from spring version `4.2` AFAIK.

```
<org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

Upgrade your spring version to `>4.2` and recheck.

Here comes the way to `dependency management`. `Spring-boot` makes it easy to go. Here is what spring boot documentation says.

- Provide opinionated 'starter' POMs to simplify your Maven
  configuration
- Automatically configure Spring whenever possible

We don't have to worry about the dependencies much apart from the Database vendor specific jars to be added as per requirement.

[API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/GenericApplicationListener.html)

*I am getting impression that Spring Boot cannot be integrated above kind of application. You need to devlop application from scratch.*

No, When we have the maven configuration with us, it is all about changing the root pom with their dependencies. Its all about dependency abstraction. Building application from root level is undoubtedly easy but by following the principles of maven, we can even make the existing application to follow spring-boot.

*Please explain me how can I take advantages of Spring Boot in already developed Spring application?*

Study about these dependencies, Analyse their root POM. They give us all the dependencies that you add in normal application. In a way helps us with build configurations and many more boiler plate dependencies.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Apart from the above,

- What is parenting in maven
- How to change version in child pom

Will help you in customizing the applications.

Comment: this happened with I was trying to migrate early spring app to the spring boot. upgrade the spring-context dependency solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add, I finished all my  R&D and solve all the problems. I created an Spring Boot application and published it over github.
https://github.com/gauravdubey58/SpringBootLegacy

In this application I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate with xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot manages dependencies for you. All dependencies in a release for springboot are tested to work together with sensible defaults.  It is possible to define you own or override, but its recommended that you do not. Refer to official documentation below :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-dependency-management

> Each release of Spring Boot is associated with a base version of the
>   Spring Framework so we highly recommend you to not specify its version
>   on your own.

For existing application it may be hard to get versions match, it surely is doable all that will depend on application complexity, time on your hand and regression testing. From migration path standpoint comment all dependencies managed by you and let springboot pull that into application e.g. spring-boot-starter-web is already pulling a spring mvc 4.2.4 while your pom define it as 4.0.3.RELEASE. This applies to other dependencis. Hibernate and spring orm will be pulled by spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

I have fully functional enterprise application with almost same dependencies by using spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter security and spring-boot-starter-freemarker and jar for DB client. But our application was fairly new when we migrated.